# AWS SNS and Ruby on Rails SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

- Rails 4.1.4
- 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.1 running Ruby 2.3 (Puma)

I am trying to use AWS SES(https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) with a rails application setup using elastic Beanstalk. I have the following in my `production.rb`

```
  ...
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    port: 587,
    user_name: ENV['SES_SMTP_USERNAME'], # Your SMTP user
    password: ENV['SES_SMTP_PASSWORD'], # Your SMTP password
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
  ...
```

But when I try to send an email I get the following error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:587:in `connect'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:587:in `tlsconnect'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:555:in `do_start'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:521:in `start'
```

The trace continues but I think that is the most important bit.

I followed the instructions listed here: https://www.sitepoint.com/deliver-the-mail-with-amazon-ses-and-rails/

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that ENV['SES_SMTP_USERNAME'] and ENV['SES_SMTP_PASSWORD'] are available to your app? You might want to log their values to check. Those instructions put it in development.rb which will not work for a production app. You probably don't want to put it in production.rb for security reasons but where to put it depends on your server stack (apache, nginx, unicorn, passenger, puma, etc) and which version of Rails you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I am positive that the ENV variables are available to config file. I think the issue may be the *port*. For some reasons `port: 465` seemed to resolve the issue. Still investigating.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like setting the port to 465 solved the issue.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  port: 465,
  user_name: ENV['SES_SMTP_USERNAME'], # Your SMTP user
  password: ENV['SES_SMTP_PASSWORD'], # Your SMTP password
  authentication: :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```